# Time complexity of a specific function in python

Tags: python, time-complexity

Hi I'm trying to understand why the time complexity of the next function:

```
def f(n):
    result = 0
    jump = 1
    cur = 0
    while cur < n:
        result += cur
        if jump*jump < n:
            jump *= 2
        cur += jump
    return result
```

is O(√n). I understand that the code under the if statement inside the function gets executed until `jump` >= √n, I also noticed that `cur` = 1 + 2 + 4 + 8 + 16 + ... but I still can't get the answer.

Comment: Is the answer completely correct? What do you think it should be?

Comment: the answer is O(√n), its a question from a test but I don't understand the reason behind it

Comment: technically it's not √n complexity, maybe a little less for bigger numbers. for ex, I tried f(2500) and it looks like that was 44 loop iterations, though I expected 50; but I think √n would be a decent estimate in any case.

Comment: yes since √n is a tight upper bound, my question is why this is the answer I'm trying to understand how to get to the answer

Comment: @rv.kvetch That's not how time complexity works.

Comment: @LielAzulay You can plot the data and compare to common runtimes (i.e., `log(n)`, `n!`, `√n`, `n^2`, etc.). Then you would just find good enough fit. If you want a mathematical approach where you deduce accurate runtime from just the code, I think it might be trickier. Which approach are you looking for?

Comment: You may want to add `print(cur)` (and  maybe `print(jump)`) to the loop to observe how the values change, and more importantly, how many times the loop actually executes.

Comment: In short: how many times can you double `jump` before `cur` exceeds `n`?

Answer (score 3):

A little math is needed here.

Suppose that `jump^2` is greater than or equal to `n` after `m` iterations, and then the `jump` will not be doubled again. Here we have:

```
jump = 2^m >= √n
```

At this time, `cur` is:

```
cur = 1 + 2 + 4 + ... + 2^m = 2 ^ (m + 1) - 1
```

Then, our total number of iterations will not be greater than:

```
          n - (2 ^ (m + 1) - 1)
m + ceil( --------------------- )
                  2^m
```

Because we have `2^m >= √n` and `2 ^ (m - 1) < √n`, so

```
            n - (2 ^ (m + 1) - 1)
  m + ceil( --------------------- )
                    2^m
                  n - 2√n + 1
< (log √n + 1) + (----------- + 1)
      2               √n
           n + 1
= log √n + -----
     2      √n
```

Here, it is clear that `(n + 1) / √n` is `O(√n)`, and the logarithm is also `O(√n)`, so the sum of the two is `O(√n)`.

<sub>Because it is about time complexity, we can prove it more loosely. For example, before `jump` reaches `√n`, it is `O(log_2 √n)` complexity, and after that, it is `O(√n)` complexity. The sum of the two is obviously `O(√n)` complexity.</sub>